# Tkinter, help a noob understand Tk's loops

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I am Python 3 noob creating a checkers game, I have a bunch of functions... and my game's loop is as follows:

```
while EndGame==0:
    PrintBoard()
    PrintBoardGui()
    print("################","\n","Player 1","\n","################","\n")
    Player=1
    PlayerSelectPiece()
    MovePiece()
    PrintBoard()
    PrintBoardGui()
    print("################","\n","Player 2","\n","################","\n")
    Player=2
    if NbrPlayer==2:
        PlayerSelectPiece()
    else:
        AiSelectPiece()
    MovePiece()
```

PrintBoardGui() that I run at the beggining of each turn and creates a Tkinter window and draws the board on a new Canvas in a Tkinter Frame.
After that, I have to close the window in order for the program to continue.
I know this is a sub-optimal solution.

I have looked around trying to understand Tkinter's loops and read a bit about the after() function but i really don't know how I could implement it in my code.

Ultimatly I would like my Tkinter window to stay open (mabye disabled or something) while I input stuff in the console to move the pieces. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

At first, how do you want to interact with your game ?

- With text in the console ?
- With buttons ?
- With keyboard/mouse event ?

The "after" method is used to refresh your screen after an amount of time.
It will call the method that you pass through the parameters.
You shouldn't have to put an infinite loop in it. But you will have to check with a simple condition the game ending, to display another screen.

If you have to use the console entry, it can be a bit hard for a beginner to manage the GUI update and the console.

Comment: I use console to interact with the game, the user inputs the row then the column of the desired piece to move. I am not too good with Tkinter I had the idea of packing buttons instead of "merely' drawing the board on a canvas that way the user could select the piece directly in the Tkinter window. But I find it pretty hard, I was trying to Display thkinter canvas of the board then, instead of destroying Tkinter window to input in console, leave the window open so the user could see the board while inputting in console.

Comment: You could use a Canvas method to find on which piece the player clicked or case. It would be better than freeze your gui or use an other thread to get the console entry.

Comment: I was thinking about the after method. If you split your window creation and the drawing method, you don't have to use the after method and don't have to destroy your window, since you are waiting for the console to get a user input. You can use your draw method after the user input to refresh your gui. You just have to split better your program functions: window creation, gui update, get user input and game ending, at least

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what ur question was but, If you would want to run the code forever (until you stop it). you would have to use the `while` loop like this:

```
while "thing" == True:
    PrintBoard()
    PrintBoardGui()
    print("################","\n","Player 1","\n","################","\n")
    Player=1
    PlayerSelectPiece()
    MovePiece()
    PrintBoard()
    PrintBoardGui()
    print("################","\n","Player 2","\n","################","\n")
    Player=2
    if NbrPlayer==2:
        PlayerSelectPiece()
    else:
        AiSelectPiece()
    MovePiece()
    thing = False
```

at the end you change thing to `False` otherwise it would be infinite and it would bug.